# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied whenever I run anything in python manage.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

Im relatively new to django and I got this error two days ago and tried everything to fix it.

I tried to run as administrator and it did not work, and i tried re installing python and it didn't work as well. Also, I reintsalled the virtual environment and it didn't work as well.

I read a couple of articles including https://sebhastian.com/environmenterror-winerror-5-access-is-denied/
https://gameofthrones-croatia.com/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied/

And i still couldn't figure it out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module    
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 331, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module    
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\aggregates.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import ExtentField
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collections import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\collections.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Project\django\djangoProject\MakEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 49, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

If there's any other way to fix this please let me know

Comment: I think the issue in the way you installed libgal, please check it.

Comment: Have u Tried to Work not on onedrive